# Searching for open graph objects using substring matching

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When I want to search for an open graph object, I use an URL like this

> http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=platform

In this case, I was searching for *platform*.

Are wildcards possible? I want to do substring searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/?ids` endpoint is not for searching. It tries to resolve the given parameters (url (primary use), page name or object id), not more and not less.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url

> `/?id={url}` Represents an external URL as it relates to the Facebook social graph - shares and comments from the URL on Facebook, and any Open Graph objects associated with the URL.

Use the `/search` endpoint instead, although there's no option to search for OpenGraph objects.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search